# Conditional Format Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, conditional-formatting

I have written a conditional formatting rule for google apps script, but I am receiving an error "getConditionalFormatRules is not a function."  Can someone help me see if I made a mistake?  I want anything that is less than 50% to be red, anything between 50% and 70% to be yellow, and anything greater than 70% to be green.  Apps script documentation says that getConditionalFormatRules is a function, so not sure what's going on.

```
function percentAtMasteryConditionalFormat(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

  range.setFontSize(10);
  range.setFontFamily("Didact Gothic");
  
  var percentAtMasteryrule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenNumberLessThan(0.5)
    .setBackground("#f4c7c3")
    .setFontColor("#5F1625")
    .whenNumberBetween(0.5,0.7)
    .setBackground("#fce8b2")
    .setFontColor("#e8ba39")
    .whenNumberGreaterThan(0.7)
    .setBackground("#a8e6ce")
    .setFontColor("#264d59")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();

var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(percentAtMasteryrule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

in `var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();`

sheet needs to be a member of [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) not [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

`getConditionalFormatRules()` should be applied on Class `Sheet`. Class `Spreadsheet` is different.

**Code:**

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

...

var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(percentAtMasteryrule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

**Documentation:**

[Class ConditionalFormatBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)

Comment: Thank you!  That was a dumb mistake